# Client certificate created with OpenSSL can't be installed on iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am using a virtual private server running Ubuntu 22.04. On the VPS, I am using an Apache web server to serve content like i.e. a wiki.

To make sure only I can access the content, I have configured Apache to expect clients to authenticate themselves via client certificate.

I used OpenSSL on the Ubuntu server to create a CA and then create the client certificate with that. The client certificate is using an export password.

I can install and use the resulting client certificate without problems on Firefox on Windows 10 and on my Android phone in Chrome. So, both the certificate as well as the password seem to work fine on principle. However, the same certificate with the same export password will fail to install on my iPad claiming the password is incorrect.

### How I created the CA

I have used these OpenSSL commands to create the CA key and certificate:

**Note:** While looking for a solution for this problem, I found [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254518218) suggesting that iOS can't handle certificates created with OpenSSL 3.x. For this reason, I have used OpenSSL 1.1.1 for the commands below.

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -sha512 -days 365 -out ca.crt
```

### How I created the client certificate

These are the OpenSSL commands I used to create the client certificate:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem > client-request.pem
openssl x509 -req -in client-request.pem -days 365 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 > client-cert01.pem
```

The client key has a password assigned to it.

I then convert them to a .pfx file like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert01.pem -inkey client-key.pem -out client-cert01.pfx
```

The .pfx file has an export password assigned to it.

As mentioned, the resulting .pfx file is working on Firefox on Windows and Chrome on Android, but if I try to install the same .pfx file on my iPad with the same password, then iOS will reject the password.

[The client certificate shown as an identity in my iOS settings screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uC9W.jpg) [Entering the password has failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWQ3W.jpg)

I have tried generating the certificates and keys both with OpenSSL 3 as well as OpenSSL 1.1.1, I have tried exporting the certificate to .p12 format (although I'm not sure that makes a big difference), I have also tried creating the certificate request on a Mac Mini instead of the Linux server itself. However, none of that had any effect.

Does anyone know what the problem might be or what I might be missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for my problem. It's a bit embarassing, because it was a blatant user error.

On Firefox on Windows, you are asked for the certificate export password upon importing it.

On Chrome on Android, you are asked for the certificate export password upon importing it.

On iOS, you are asked for a "code" upon importing the certificate. However, this first password prompt is *not* referring to the export password of the certificate, but for the passcode of your iPad. The export password is prompted only after correctly entering your iPad passcode...